# MongoAlchemy embedded documents

Tags: python, flask, mongoalchemy

Does anyone know how to create a model with an embedded document with mongo alchemy? I've search in the documentation, but there isn't any example about doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at:

https://github.com/jeffjenkins/MongoAlchemy/blob/master/examples/examples.py

Theres a sample there, but for completeness, yes MongoAlchemy can use embedded documents like this:

```
class Address(Document):
    street_address = StringField()
    city = StringField()
    state_province = StringField()
    country = StringField()

class User(Document):

    name = StringField()
    email = StringField()

    address = DocumentField(Address)


user = User()
user.name = "tony"

user.address = Address()
user.address.city = "London"
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anything in `mongoAlachemy` for embedded documents:

see here:

- Schema — Document-Object Mapper and Schema Definitions — MongoAlchemy
  v0.12 documentation ->
  http://www.mongoalchemy.org/api/schema/index.html

I suggest you use `mongoengine` for better result:

- MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine · GitHub ->
  https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine
- https://flask-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#supported-fields